# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while textField becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` exception when I hit "`back`" button on `NavigationBar` of my `CreateViewController` which is `pushed` on `UINavigationController`

When I enable following line in `CreateViewController.m` (full code at the bottom)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    //[self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I start getting **`Thread1:EXE_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=...)`**

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

If I keep the above line of code disabled, then hitting back button takes me to MainViewController as expected.

I am a newbie to iOS. What I am doing wrong? Please see my code below.

---

Appdelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Appdelegate.m

```
import "AppDelegate.h"
import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    id controller  = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    id navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)create:(id)sender;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
import "MainViewController.h"
import "CreateViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)create:(id)sender {

    id controller = [[CreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
@end
```

CreateView.h

```
@interface CreateViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

CreateView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    self.textField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 160, 30)];
    [self.textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    self.textField.placeholder = @"Name";
    [self.textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.textField.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.textField];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    //[self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: why negative vote...I am genuinely looking for pointers

Comment: Add Exception breakpoints and see what line it breaks on. http://timroadley.com/2012/03/26/tip-exception-breakpoints/

Comment: What happens if you manually tap on the text field then tap the back button? Same issue?

Comment: Does this happen if you make the textField become the firstResponder in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear?

Comment: @rmaddy..same behavior

Comment: @Acey...same behavior...meaning I get exception

Comment: @user2384694 OK, that proves that the problem isn't specific to the line you commented out. It's due to the text field having the keyboard focus. Try adding something like `[self.textField resignFirstResponder];` in the `viewWillDisappear:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy...you are smart like hell...you rock...that was smart...thanks a lot...how come I did not think that before posting question...thx

Answer (score 0):

Go to breakpoint navigator and add exceptions breakpoint as shown below , 1st option :[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding self.textField as subview to navigation bar, set the textField as titleView of navigation item of the view controller.

```
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:self.textField];
```

This must help...